# Polling vs Long-polling vs Push (books and scientific papers)

Tags: push, long-polling, polling

I'm writing master's thesis and I've already wrote much about Ajax vs Comet vs WebSocket comparison based on the information I've found on the internet.
But I need some scientific research to put into reference list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing a paper on WebSocket at the moment (would love to see your work), and I've found +30 pages on the subject in "Pro HTML5 Programming" by Peter Lubbers, Brian Albers and Frank Salim.

EDIT: Actually, there's a better, or at least much more comprehensive, book about WebSocket called "The Definitive Guide to HTML5 WebSocket" by Vanessa Wang, Frank Salim and Peter Moskovits, published by the same guys who published Pro HTML5 Programming.

Comment: Thanks for the book - added to the reference list. Although the information about WebSockets is similar to http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html
BTW: My work is in latvian language.. :)

Comment: Oh, well my latvian is a little rusty, so I think I'll pass then...!

Comment: I edited my post with another book, take a look at it. Weird that no one else has come up with any references for Ajax or Comet. I could use a few myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll mark your answer as correct since you're only one who've answered my question :)